# How are Kubernetes Services implemented?

Tags: kubernetes, nginx

Ok, this may be a tough one for a K8s neophite like me, so I'll rely in the many experts that lurk the shadows here because I cannot get an answer.

I would like to know if K8s implements ClusterIP services using Nginx or not, and if not, if it is a similar implementation.  My cause of suspicion is getting 499 status codes from one internal microservice to the applciation's gateway, but both implementations are ASP.Net, and ASP.Net does not use status code 499.

The Internet says status code 499 is only used by Nginx.

So here I am, completely confused by the facts:

1. Client HTTP request reaches the gateway.
2. Gateway routes to internal HTTP server.
3. Internal HTTP server, an ASP.Net server, allegedly responds with status code 499.

So, if 499 is not coming from the ASP.Net server, who's sending it?  I can only conclude that the sender is K8s itself, the Service ClusterIP part, right?  To the gateway there's no difference, I suppose.

Thanks!  Let me know if I should clarify anything.

Comment: Kubernetes implements the ClusterIP proxy using its own proxy implementation; it does not utilize Nginx.

Comment: A Service can forward any TCP-based protocol, it doesn't have to be HTTP and there's no way to tell Kubernetes what's going over the channel.  [Virtual IPs and Service Proxies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/networking/virtual-ips/) in the Kubernetes documentation talks about some details, but these won't be interesting to typical application developers.

Comment: I see.  Thanks for stopping by guys.  What I'm after is the source of the 499 HTTP response.  Any ideas on how to track it?  I am sure ASP.Net is not sending this response, and I need to troubleshoot the issue.